# Display columns of nested dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, cryptocurrency

I pulled some cryptocurrency data and the information is in a nested dictionary. I was able to "isolate" the information I want by accessed the keys for the first dictionary and the prices and other info by the following code:

```
c = df['quote'][9]['USD']['price']
```

However I want this in a table. I was able to convert the dictionary to a DataFrame; however, I cannot get the nested dictionary inside the column out of the column into its own dataframe to assign columns. I would like to do this for all 100 rows. I already transposed the data frame from 100 columns to 1 column with 100 rows. A sample of the text inside the dataframe is below. I am newish to python but I have tried functions, for loops, while loops. Any help would be appreciated.

```
0   {'price': 13574.815756488579, 'volume_24h': 30...
1   {'price': 385.0299121331971, 'volume_24h': 137...
2   {'price': 1.00094922868182, 'volume_24h': 4848...
3   {'price': 0.23929041807117, 'volume_24h': 2399...
4   {'price': 262.15395834212285, 'volume_24h': 31...
```

This is what the nested dictionary looks like inside the quote (highest-level) dictionary (each nested dictionary in each row has all of the below information):

```
#{'USD': {'price': 385.0299121331971,
   #'volume_24h': 13795520312.19678,
   #'percent_change_1h': 0.47915019,
   #'percent_change_24h': -1.02234395,
   #'percent_change_7d': -5.72396664,
   #'market_cap': 43594479232.334625,
   #'last_updated': '2020-10-30T22:10:03.000Z'}},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
df = df['column_name'].apply(pd.Series)
```

Where pd is pandas, df is your dataframe and "column_name" is the name of the column containing the dictionaries.

Comment: Great suggestion! I still get a key error when I try to call the column name of "quote".  
```
KeyError: 'quote'
```

Comment: As I understand, there's no column named "quote" in your dataframe. What's the name of the column that has the dictionaries in your dataframe? Replace "column_name" with the name and it will work

Comment: If your dataframe has one single column without a name, then you can first do:

df.columns = ["temporary"]

and then

df = df['temporary'].apply(pd.Series)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirement correctly, this code should get the result you want.

```
import pandas as pd

dd = {
'USD': {'price': 385.0299, 'volume_24h': 13795520312.19678, 'percent_change_1h': 0.4791},
'BTC': {'price': 485.0299, 'volume_24h': 23795520312.19678, 'percent_change_1h': 0.5791},
'ETH': {'price': 585.0299, 'volume_24h': 33795520312.19678, 'percent_change_1h': 0.6791},
'BGD': {'price': 685.0299, 'volume_24h': 43795520312.19678, 'percent_change_1h': 0.7791}
}

d2 = {k:[] for k in dd[list(dd.keys())[0]]}
for k in d2:
   for k2 in dd:
      d2[k].append(dd[k2][k])

d2['sym'] = list(dd)

print(d2,'\n')

df = pd.DataFrame(d2)

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Output

```
{'price': [385.0299, 485.0299, 585.0299, 685.0299], 
 'volume_24h': [13795520312.19678, 23795520312.19678, 33795520312.19678, 43795520312.19678], 
 'percent_change_1h': [0.4791, 0.5791, 0.6791, 0.7791], 
 'sym': ['USD', 'BTC', 'ETH', 'BGD']}

    price    volume_24h  percent_change_1h  sym
 385.0299  1.379552e+10             0.4791  USD
 485.0299  2.379552e+10             0.5791  BTC
 585.0299  3.379552e+10             0.6791  ETH
 685.0299  4.379552e+10             0.7791  BGD
```

Comment: I ran your code with the data you have in the reply and it works! Yet, it does not work with my data in my ipynb. I ran this and I got the error "TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'"

USD is not the name of the currency, it is the currency that the cryptocurrency is represented by. That dictionary info is the crypotcurrency information for BTC. Not sure if that is helpful.